# For what values of x is $\csc(3x-\frac{π}4)$ continuous?

Tags: functions

The question is for what values of $x$ is 
$\csc(3x-\frac{π}4)$ continuous ?

So I tried to determine the domain of the function by first converting it to  $\frac{1}{\sin(3x-\frac{π}4)}$.

This resulted in  $R(\frac{π}{12} + kπ : k∈Z)$ which is wrong but why???

The solution is: $R(\frac{π}{12} + \frac{2kπ}{3}; \frac{5π}{12} + \frac{2kπ}{3}  : k∈Z)$

Comment: $3x-\frac{\pi}{4} \neq n \pi$ means $$x \neq \frac{(4n+1)\pi}{12}$$

Comment: The $R$ notation is not a conventional one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that
$$\sin(3x-\frac{π}4)=0$$
if and only if
$$
3x-\frac{\pi}{4}=k\pi, \quad \text{for some  }\ \ k\in{\mathbb{Z}}
$$
if and only if
$$
x=\frac13\left(k\pi+\frac{\pi}{4}\right),\quad \text{for some  }\ \ k\in{\mathbb{Z}}
$$
if and only if
$$
x=\frac{k\pi}{3}+\frac{\pi}{12},\quad \text{for some  }\ \ k\in{\mathbb{Z}}
$$

So the domain of the function can be written as
$$
S = \mathbb{R}\setminus Q
$$
where
$$
Q=\{\frac{k\pi}{3}+\frac{\pi}{12}:k\in{\mathbb Z}\}.
$$

---

Note also that the set
$$
\left\{\frac{\pi}{12}+\frac{2k\pi}{3};\frac{5\pi}{12}+\frac{2k\pi}{3}:k\in{\mathbb Z}\right
\}
$$
is the same as the set $Q$ above since
$$
\frac{5\pi}{12}+\frac{2k\pi}{3}=\frac{\pi}{12}+\frac{(2k+1)\pi}{3}.
$$

Answer (score 2):

The correct solution is
$$3x-\frac\pi 4 \not\equiv 0\mod\pi\iff 3x \not\equiv  \frac\pi 4\mod\pi\iff x \not\equiv  \frac\pi {12}\mod\frac\pi{\color{red}3}.$$

Comment: I understand what you're doing there but I don't get it how I can convert this in the solution: $R(\frac{π}{12} + \frac{2kπ}{3}; \frac{5π}{12} + \frac{2kπ}{3}  : k∈Z)$

Comment: They take representatives in the interval $[0,\frac\pi2]$: there are $2$ of them: $\frac\pi{12}$ and $\frac\pi{12}+\frac\pi3=\frac{5\pi}{12}$, whence the two congruences modulo $\frac{2\pi}3$, instead of a single congruence modulo $\frac\pi3$.